# Differences between minimization functions?

Tags: mathematical-optimization, core-language, language-design

There's more than 20 functions having to do with minimization

```
MinMax, ConstrainedMin, NMinimize, NArgMin, FindMinimumCut, 
NMinValue, MinLimit, Minimize, DiscreteMinLimit, MinValue, ArgMin, 
FindMinimum, BooleanMinterms, FindMinValue, RankedMin, FindArgMin, 
MinimalBy, Min, BooleanMinimize, BayesianMinimization, MinDate
```

What is each of them for?  Are there patterns to help remember them?

Answer (score 5):

Looking at `Names["*Min*"]`, we find all functions that involve "Min" in their name.

#### function minimization

These symbols have to do with finding local and global minima for functions (i.e. $f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$)

```
FindArgMin,   NArgMin,   ArgMin,   (*gives argument(s) of minimum*)
FindMinimum,  NMinimize, Minimize, (*gives list(s) {arg,value}*)
FindMinValue, NMinValue, MinValue  (*gives value(s) of minimum*)
```

The middle row is all that really matters

- `Find*Min` is numerical, and iteratively steps toward a local min from a starting point.
- `N*Min` is semi-numerical, and looks for a global min.
- The right column finds exact non-numerical minima, unless it can't in which case it actually calls the numerical ones.

#### discrete minimization

- `Min` gives the smallest value of a list
- `RankedMin` gives the $n$th smallest value of a list
- `MinimalBy` allows the use of a function to evaluate smallness.  Since different elements could evaluate to the same number, it returns all minimal elements instead of just one

---

There are other functions that have to do with minimizing on different pieces of data, like booleans, graphs, colors, dates, sequences, etc.

For each of the functions, there's a maximization counterpart (except `MinMax` which is just `{Min@#,Max@#}&`).

The functions aren't named perfectly: `Minimize` being related to `MinValue` but not to `Min` is annoying.

Comment: Pretty good synopsis. One thing to note: the exact functions will not invoke numeric counterparts unless the input contains approximate values.